# Send E-mail to SharePoint? Exchange is installed on same server

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, exchange-2010

If this is even possible, what I need to do...

My organization has a single sharepoint installation.  On this same box, Exchange 2k10 is installed and running with all of the roles for that instance (mailbox, hub transport, etc).

It has been expressed that I need to have sharepoint listen to it's SMTP service on the box, and accept incoming E-mail (for announcements, etc - one of sharepoints core features).

BUUUUUT - since Exchange is already running on that box, is this even an option?  And, if it in fact IS a possibility - please point me to a configuration sampling.

ANY information you guys can throw my way, would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install an STMP service - SharePoint can pick up incoming emails from a drop folder on the hard disk or direct from an email server so you shouldn't have any problems with Exchange on the same box.

See "Using an Advanced scenario"

[TechNet - Plan incoming e-mail (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288433.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for this information - I will be checking in to this very shortly.